# Создание сервера для одиночной игры

Tags: сервер

Хотел поинтересоваться, где можно почитать подробную информацию о серверах для игр. Есть детская мечта — преобразовать обычную инди игру в мультиплеер, хотя бы для двоих, но не понимаю, как это работает, кроме того, что сервер должен передавать информацию о мире двум игрокам. Все пытался найти статьи/видео, как это сделать, но что-то уже сдался и решил написать.

Я ориентируюсь на подобные игры, как: SAMP, GTA RP.

Answer (score 0):

Для Samp/Crmp/MTA тебе нужен ЯП Pawn.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но меня не самп волнует, а то, как это устроено. Как люди придумали мультилплеер, как сервер создавался, просто довольно глухо об этом. Возможно, я некорректно задал вопрос.

Comment: Фактически, мультиплеер - мод для игры. Всё висит на UDP/TCP протоколе, просто пишут мод, но чтобы это все работало в онлайне.

Comment: А декомпиляция игры нужна будет, если это просто инди? Наверно, в любом случае нужна будет

Comment: Кстати, а условно этот "сервер" для инди игры, я же могу держать у себя просто на ПК и делиться с другим пользователем? Возможно, что это небезопасно, конечно

Comment: Если у игры есть своя мод тулза, то декомпиляция не нужна. Просто берете и читаете доки. У себя конечно можете держать сервер, но он может лагать, падать